# Condition on $F$ such that $U^\prime \subseteq U\cap F$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a metric space. What condition should be assumed on a closed set $F$ such that, for every non-empty open set $U$, there exists another non-empty open set $U^\prime$ such that
$$
U^\prime \subseteq U\cap F?
$$

(I mean non-trivial condition: e.g. avoid "set $X=F$".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, we need $F=X$ (see Henno Brandsma's answer). However, what if we only consider open sets $U$ that intersect $F$?

From $U' \subseteq U\cap F$ we know that $U' \subseteq F^\circ$, where $F^\circ:=\bigcup\{A\subseteq F \mid A\ \text{is open}\}$ denotes the interior of $F$. This means that every open set intersecting $F$ must also intersect the interior of $F$. A class of closed sets satisfying this condition are called regular closed sets.

A set $A$ is a **regular closed** set if $A = \overline{A^\circ}$. We prove that a closed set satisfies your (modified) condition if and only if the set is regularly closed.

*Proof:*
If $F$ is regular closed and $U\cap F\ne\emptyset$, then $U\cap\overline{F^\circ}\ne\emptyset$ and consequently $U\cap F^\circ \ne\emptyset$. Taking $U':=U\cap F^\circ$ gives a nonempty open set satisfying $U'\subseteq U\cap F$.

Conversely, suppose $F$ satisfies the condition. Since $\overline{F^\circ}\subseteq \overline{F} = F$, it suffices to prove $F\subseteq \overline{F^\circ}$.
To this end, fix $x$ in $F$ and let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $x$. Then $x\in U\cap F$ so that $U\cap F\ne\emptyset$. By hypothesis there exists a nonempty open set $U'$ such that $U'\subseteq U\cap F$. As we remarked before, $U'\subseteq F^\circ$ and hence $U\cap F^\circ \supseteq U' \ne \emptyset$. We have shown that every neighborhood of $x$ meets $F^\circ$. Therefore $x\in\overline{F^\circ}$, which proves that $F$ is regular closed. $\square$

Note that none of this requires $X$ to be a metric space.

Comment: So in a metric space, regular closed sets are the same as the open sets?

Comment: Nice answer. However it seems you are using the fact that if $U,V$ are non-empty disjoint open sets, then $U \cap \overline{V}=\emptyset$. Why this is true?

Comment: @AOrtiz No that isn't true. For instance, on $\mathbb{R}$ the interval $[0,1]$ is regular closed and not open. I don't have enough reputation to comment on your answer, so I'll have to leave it here. When proving that $F$ is open, how do you know that the $U'$ contains $x$?

Comment: @Nduccio I'm not sure exactly where you find that I'm using that. I use that a point $x$ is in $\overline{A}$ iff every neighborhood of $x$ meets $A$. Using this "definition" of closure, one can prove that an open set $U$ meets $A$ iff $U$ meets $\overline{A}$.

Comment: @JohnGriffin In other words, given $U,V$ with $U$ open, then $U \cap V =\emptyset$ iff $U \cap \overline{V}=\emptyset$, is it correct?

Comment: @Nduccio Exactly! If $U\cap V = \emptyset$, then $V \subseteq U^c$. Since $U^c$ is closed, we have that $\overline{V} \subseteq U^c$ and thus $U\cap\overline{V} = \emptyset$.

Comment: Great answer John, and welcome on MSE :)

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done, for suppose $F$ is non-empty closed and proper, set $U = X\setminus F$ and then $U \cap F =\emptyset$ contains no non-empty open (open) set...
So only $F=X$ is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be a non-trivial closed set. Since for every non-empty  open set $U$, there exists a non-empty open set $U^\prime$ such that $U^\prime\subseteq U\cap F$ we must have $U\cap F\neq \emptyset$. That is for every non-empty open set $U$, $U\cap F\neq \emptyset$ which is impossible since $X$ is normal (any metric space is normal). So we can't have what you want.