# Perfect Vs Regular Closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an Hausdorff space such that $\{x\}$ is not open for each $x \in X$. A subset $A$ is said to be regular closed if it is closed and $U\cap A\neq \emptyset$ for some open $U$ implies that there exists an open $U' \neq \emptyset$ such that $U^\prime \subseteq U\cap A$. It particular, $A$ has no isolated points, hence $A$ is perfect.

> **Question.** Is there some relation between perfect sets of $X$ and regular closed sets of $X$?

Comment: Didn't you forget that $U'$ must be open too? Like this you can just take $U'=U\cap A$.

Comment: If $X$ is Hausdorff, then $\{x\}$ is always closed.

Comment: Of course $U'$ and $\{x\}$ were meant to be open. I just want to avoid trivial situations as the discrete topology

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a space that has no isolated points. So no $\{x\}$ is **open**.

Then every regular closed set (the usual definition is that $A=\overline{\operatorname{int}(A)}$) is perfect. The reverse need not hold as the Cantor set shows.

Comment: I already wrote in the OP the every regular closed set is perfect.. I was meaning some other relations

Comment: @Nduccio I claim regular closed implies regular but not reversely.

Comment: Ok now it is clear what you mean, but this just follows from the definitions..

Comment: @Nduccio you use a non-standard definition of regular closed.

Comment: Nope, this is equivalent to your classical definition, see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376092/condition-on-f-such-that-u-prime-subseteq-u-cap-f

Comment: So I think except regular closed implies perfect is all that can really be said.

Comment: I was hoping in something different, but thanks anyway Henno (I will accept your answer in some days if there will be nothing else here)